# Call WinRT Async method from Powershell to set account picture in win8

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to put something together that will use the AD Thumbnail photo to set a user's account picture on Windows 8.  It seems like I should be able to use the API from WinRT to do this.  I've pieced something together from various sources about calling the API from powershell, but I can't get it working.  Here's an example of what I've tried to do:

```
$photo = ([ADSISEARCHER]“samaccountname=$($username)”).findone().properties.thumbnailphoto
$path = "C:\temp\Photo.jpg"
$photo | set-content $path -encoding byte


[Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation,Windows.System.UserProfile,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] > $null
[Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation]::SetAccountPictureAsync($photo)
```

I've tried a couple of other variations, but no matter what I do, I end up with an error like this:

```
Cannot convert argument "image", with value: "System.Object[]", for "setAccountPictureAsync" to type "Windows.Storage.IStorageFile" . . .
```

Is there something simple that I'm missing here to make this work?

I found [this blog post by Keith Hill](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2013/09/30/calling-winrt-async-methods-from-windows-powershell/) which seems like it might be helpful, but I am not sure if it directly translates to the issue I'm having.

Thanks!

Aurock

Answer (score 5):

https://fleexlab.blogspot.com/2018/02/using-winrts-iasyncoperation-in.html has a pure-PowerShell solution.

```bsh
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]
function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType) {
 $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
 $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
 $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
 $netTask.Result
}
```

This could then be used as:

```bsh
$photoPath = "$home\Pictures\Photo.jpg"
$file = Await ([Windows.Storage.StorageFile]::GetFileFromPathAsync($photoPath)) ([Windows.Storage.StorageFile])
$result = Await ([Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation]::SetAccountPictureAsync($file)) ([Windows.System.UserProfile.SetAccountPictureResult])
```

Answer (score 1):

`SetAccountPicture` expects an object implementing IStorageFile and not a byte array.  I would save the picture to your Pictures folder then load that into a StorageFile as shown below. You should be able to pass that object into the SetAccountPicture() method e.g.

```
$photoPath = "$home\Pictures\Photo.jpg"
$asyncOp = [Windows.Storage.StorageFile]::GetFileFromPathAsync($photoPath)
$typeName = 'PoshWinRT.AsyncOperationWrapper[Windows.Storage.StorageFile]'
$wrapper = new-object $typeName -Arg $asyncOp
$file = $wrapper.AwaitResult()

$asyncOp = [Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation]::SetAccountPictureAsync($file)
$typeName = 'PoshWinRT.AsyncOperationWrapper[Windows.System.UserProfile.SetAccountPictureResult]'
$wrapper = new-object $typeName -Arg $asyncOp
$result = $wrapper.AwaitResult()
$wrapper.Dispose()
```

Comment: Keith - Thanks for the answer.  I'm having trouble compiling your wrapper though.  Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Here's the command I'm running, under windows 8.1 Pro:

c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild c:\temp\poshwinrt-master\poshwinrt.sln

Comment: AsyncOperationWrapper.cs(9,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAsyn
cOperation' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembl
y reference?) [c:\temp\poshwinrt-master\PoshWinRT\PoshWinRT.csproj]
AsyncOperationWrapper.cs(40,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Asyn
cStatus' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly r
eference?) [c:\temp\poshwinrt-master\PoshWinRT\PoshWinRT.csproj]

Comment: You used the project file from the repo as well, right? It has been hand modified to compile a WinRT dll.

Comment: I downloaded the zip of the whole repo from github and extracted it to c:\temp.  I'm not sure what all in the msbuild output is relevant.  I'm a server admin that does some simple powershell scripting, not a programmer, so compiling code is not something I have much experience with.  
I am getting a few warnings in addition to the error, but I can't include the entire output here due to character limit.

Comment: FWIW, I installed VS Express 2013 for Windows and for Windows Desktop.  Using the Desktop version, I am getting the same errors when trying to compile from the most recent commit on github.  The "Windows" version won't do anything with the current commit, it states that "This edition of Visual Studio only supports Windows Store apps."

I downloaded the previous commit from github, and was able to compile that successfully using VS Express 2013 for Windows.  I'll give the dll a shot this afternoon and see if it works for me.

Comment: Yeah this is a bit of an odd beast because we're creating a Windows Store library for use in a desktop application.  It wouldn't surprise me if you can't get there from here with the Express versions of VS.

Comment: The wrapper seems to be working, but I'm still not getting the results I want.  Using the example you provided, I get an error `Exception calling "Awaitresult" with "0" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred."`

I was able to get the image assigned to $file by changing the asyncOp to  '$asyncOp = [Windows.Storage.StorageFile]::GetFileFromAsync($path)` 

Then when I get down to the 2nd part, I get another error.  Is the $typename you listed correct?  Not knowing anything about windows API's, just based on context, I expected [Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.SetAccountPicture]

Comment: When I run the 2nd part as you provided, it seems to go through ok, but at the end, $result returns "Failure", and the picture remains unchanged.

Comment: The updated script is pretty much what I was ended up with at the end of the day yesterday.  The script runs successfully, but after it runs the account picture isn't changed.  After its done I type "$result" at the prompt, and it returns "Failure".

Comment: I unmarked this as answered for now, since I'm still not able to get it working.  I'm not sure how to identify what exactly is failing, or get more information, since the failure seems to be happening with the api call inside the wrapper.