# Windows Clipboard History - How to view the history from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, clipboard, history, windows-11

Currently I'm trying to figure out how to use Clipboard history in PowerShell.
I know that Get-Clipboard -command shows you the last item in Clipboard, but how to access those 25 others?
Using Windows + V you can see values stored in the history and it has to save those values somewhere in the RAM. On top of that there is file saved in %localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Clipboard named HistoryData and under that is some hex file, but I can't figure if that is somehow relevant for my search of if it's just another "Red herring".
(Get-Clipboard).count only shows 1.

Comment: everything i can find online says that the data is stored in RAM ... so you likely need to use a call to some part of windows to grab that info. i can't find anything on how to do that, tho. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: Use `Windows.ApplicationModel.Clipboard.GetHistoryItemsAsync` in conjunction with [awaiting from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194315/) to get the `ClipboardHistoryItemsResult`. You can then iterate through the `Items` and call `GetTextAsync` (say) to get the text of each history item.

Comment: how exactly? what command in powershell? @Raymond Chen

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230303-00/?p=107894

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for the command using `Get-Help Get-Clipboard` you will see that it really does only show you the *current entry* - not a full history

```
NAME
    Get-Clipboard

SYNOPSIS
    Gets the current Windows clipboard entry.
```